# AngularJS - updating scope value with asynchronous response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to share some data between AngularJS controllers. Also I get the data through http request. When I access the data from controller, it is null and later (if manually refresh through UI), the data is available. I am guessing the issue is very similar to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179488/the-view-is-not-updated-in-angularjs)
But whatever I tried in my case didn't work. Please see the fiddle

http://plnkr.co/edit/6SkzXK?p=preview

so, in controller I get the data through

```
//myService.setName(); //commented as it breaks the code
```

which sets the value in service and access through `getName()`

it most likely could be solved through, `$rootScope.$apply` , as in the above link but I couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problems is that when your controller is initialized, you copy the result of getName() to a variable `$scope.name = myService.getName()`. Since `$scope.name` is holding a string and not a reference it will not be updated when `getName()` changes.

There are 3 ways to resolve this.

1. make `$scope.name = myService.getName` and use it as an function `Hello {{name()}}`.
2. make `myService.getName()` return an object like `{ real_name: "foo" }` and use `name.real_name` on the view
3. bind `myService` to the scope and direct use the `getName` function `$scope.myService = myService;`and on views `myService.getName()`

I prefer the first, given is more clear. The second is good when you have more data. The third isn't a good way in my opnion.

Comment: Thank you I have had the same problem and this helped me a lot in understanding.

Answer (score 0):

There are three things you need to do to get your plunker to work:

1. Inject the $http service into the new service
2. Define the getName() function that the view is calling
3. Pass the $scope in to the setName() function and change the value on the $scope

http://plnkr.co/edit/6SkzXK