# How to use ng-class or angular.element correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I am receiving dynamically data (in json format), and need to change the background images of buttons. Every buttons have ids so its easy to know, which button will be manupulated.

But I am having problem, when I try to manupulate the background-image of a button dynamically.

Example buttons:

```
<button id="1111_1111_c">Value1</button>
<button id="2222_2222_d">Value1</button>
```

I have tried to manupulate like so: (with JQuery)

```
var btnId = '2222_2222_d';
$('#' + btnId).css('background-image','url(images/btn_red.gif)');
```

but it happens nothing. If I try the same as pure JQuery, it works.

I know there is angular dom-updater or event to update the dom. But dont know how to do that.

Is there a solution with directives or using ng-class ?

Thank You!

Comment: button with background-image and .gif ?

Comment: Have you put your code inside document ready handler?

Comment: @l2aelba whats wrong with background-image and gif? its a matter of taste

Comment: @undefined I am not trying to get it to work with JQuery. its about angularJs. But yes its work in document ready. I should explain more clearly

Comment: @Vury I will using <div> so style="cursor:pointer" more compatibility

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Angular, we want to think about changing model/$scope properties, which will then automatically update the HTML view.  (We don't want/need to work with IDs.)  So declare a model property on the button that you want to change:

```
<button ng-class="button_1111_class" id=...>Value1</button>
```

(Above, button_1111_class is a property on $scope.)  Then, when you get your data, modify your button_1111_class model data in your controller, e.g.:

```
$scope.button_1111_class = 'red_bg_image';  // red_bg_image is a CSS class you define
```

and your view should update automatically.

If you are getting your data outside AngularJS, you may need to wrap your model/$scope changes in $scope.$apply():  [The view is not updated in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179488/the-view-is-not-updated-in-angularjs)

Comment: How can I call the button with a class, when they are gettin created dynamically? is it possible: $scope[button_1111_class] = 'red_bg_image'; ? Because I dont know the classname

Comment: What is getting created dynamically, buttons and/or the background images for those buttons?  (I thought the buttons already existed and you were only changing the background images.)  Can you create a fiddle showing your problem? http://pkozlowskios.wordpress.com/2012/08/12/using-jsfiddle-with-angularjs/