# How do I update one controller with data from another controller with a service in angular?

Tags: json, angularjs

I have 2 controllers. The first gets the selected item the second gets the available items.

How can I display the new selected item?

The button underneath each available item has a ng-click that calls a service called updateItem where I would like the update to happen.

I have been working on this for awhile any help is much appreciated.
-Thanks

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whnSs/135/)

```
<div ng-controller="seletedItemCtrl">
      <p><i>I want to update this item</i></p>
      <div ng-repeat="item in selectedItems">

      <ul>
          <li>{{item.color}}</li>
          <li>{{item.Distance}}</li>
          <li>{{item.height}}</li>
          <li>{{item.name}}</li>
          <li>{{item.year}}</li>
      </ul>
   </div>
</div >   
  ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
  <div ng-controller="availableItemsCtrl">
       <div ng-repeat="item in availableItems">
          <ul>
              <li>{{item.color}}</li> 
              <li>{{item.Distance}}</li>
              <li>{{item.height}}</li>
              <li>{{item.name}}</li>
              <li>{{item.year}}</li>
         </ul>
         <button ng-click = 'updateItem()' >select item</button>
      </div> 
   </div>
```

JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function availableItemsCtrl($rootScope, $scope){
        $scope.availableItems =  {
    "Items": {
        "Item": {
            "Group1": [
                {
                    "color": "White",
                    "Distance": "NA",
                    "height": "3ft",
                    "name": "Underlift",
                    "year": "1955"

                  },
                  {
                    "color": "blue",
                    "Distance": "4M",
                    "height": "2ft",
                    "name": "Underlift",
                    "year": "1956"

                  },
                  {
                     "color": "red",
                     "Distance": "NA",
                     "height": "3ft",
                     "name": "Golen Leaf",
                     "year": "1968"

                   },
                   {
                      "color": "yellow",
                      "Distance": "22M",
                      "height": "10in",
                      "name": "Together",
                      "year": "1988"

                   }


              ]
          },

       }
   }
       $scope.availableItems = $scope.availableItems.Items.Item.Group1;
 }

 function seletedItemCtrl($rootScope, $scope){
         $scope.seletedItem =  {
              "Items":{
                  "Item":{
                     "Group1":[{

                         "color": "black",
                         "Distance": "2M",
                         "height": "1in",
                         "name": "never",
                         "year": "1922"

                          }
                       ]
                     }
                   }
                 }
    $scope.selectedItems = $scope.seletedItem.Items.Item.Group1;

  }
    app.service("updateItem", function(){

      console.log('update item');

   });
```

Comment: @pkozlowski.opensource, he did provide a fiddle (I think you just missed it in the text).

Comment: Oops, sorry, you are right!

Answer (score 7):

Remeber that your `$scope` is not your model; your `$scope` is the thing you *attach your model to*. Angular encourages you to build your own model objects that describe your application's behavior. In this example, it seems you have domain concepts of "available items" and "selected items." Here's a simple service that gives you a model for those concepts:

```
app.factory('Items', function () {
    var Items = {
        availableItems: [],
        selectedItems: []
    };
    Items.addAvailableItem = function (item) {
        Items.availableItems.push(item);
    };
    Items.selectItem = function (item) {
        Items.selectedItems.push(item);
    };
    return Items;
});
```

So now you have this `Items` service, which has an `addAvailableItem` method, which takes an item and adds it to the `availableItems` array, and a `selectItem` method, which takes an item and adds it to the `selectedItems` array. You can now bind those two arrays to your view using a controller's scope:

```
app.controller('someController', function ($scope, Items) {
    $scope.availableItems = Items.availableItems;
};
```

Here's a jsFiddle that demonstrates the concept using the code you provided as a starting point (it also demonstrates a better way to define your controllers in a module): http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/kV4mK/

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt:  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/XeEjb/).

I didn't quite understand your data structures, so I changed them a bit.  However, I think the important part is there -- how to share the data between the controllers.

```
function availableItemsCtrl($rootScope, $scope, itemService) {
    $scope.availableItems = [{
        "color": "White",
         ...
    }];
    $scope.updateItem = itemService.storeSelectedItem;
    itemService.storeSelectedItem($scope.availableItems[0]);
}

function selectedItemCtrl($scope, itemService) {
    $scope.selectedItem = itemService.selectedItem;
}

app.service("itemService", function () {
    var that = this;
    this.selectedItem = {};
    this.storeSelectedItem = function (item) {
        angular.copy(item, that.selectedItem);
        console.log('update item', item);
    }
});
```

It took me a (long) while to figure out that I had to use angular.copy() instead of

```
that.selectedItem = item;
```

because the above would cause selectedItem to be assigned a new array reference, which  selectedItemCtrl wouldn't notice -- i.e., $scope.selectedItem would still be referencing the previous array.

I will be interested to see what others come up with.

**Update:** looks like I completely missed the fact that you wanted to support multiple selected items.

Comment: This demonstrates the concept beautifully--I wouldn't beat yourself up over the details of the particular domain model, as it wasn't very clear.

Comment: Thanks @Brandon.  I like your use of factory() instead of service() -- I never liked the `this` `that` stuff.  I also like how you moved all of the models into the service.  (I must start doing that more.)

Comment: Thanks :) I usually use CoffeeScript, which pretty much negates the need for `this`/`that`. Moving all the data out of the `$scope` and into services can be tricky to get into the habit of doing, but it pays off exponentially when it comes time to change the domain model around!