# Separate models from controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have something like this -

```
function DetailCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.persons = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Mark"
    }];        
}
```

I'd like to keep the models separate from the controller, like this -

```
    //models
    var person = { id: '', name: '' };

    function DetailCtrl($scope) {
       person = db.getPerson();
       $scope.person = person;
    }
```

Is this a good practice in angularjs? I come from ASP.NET MVC background.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Angular maintains a two-way binding (the viewmodel) between view and controller. Separating the model from the controller breaks this dynamic.

Comment: This is a best practice idea -- models should be referenced by the scope/controllers, not contained in them (see my answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is a best practice to have your models elsewhere, and have your scopes reference your models: [listen to 2 minutes of Misko](http://youtu.be/ZhfUv0spHCY?t=30m) from his "Best Practices" video.

Services are a good place to store your models.
Brandon has a good answer related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14667066/215945

Comment: Thank you. I've added my models in Services and it work great.