# not updating view after Ajax call in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am calling get method but the view is not updated. I tried `alert()` and it shows data properly.

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
    $.get( "people/allNumberOfuser", function( data )
    {
        $scope.testValue =data.message;
        alert(data.message);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
    <p ng-controller="TestCtrl">
        {{testValue}}
    </p>
</div>
```

I am new in AngularJS. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use AngularJS's `$http` service for the HTTP calls. Please read more about it [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). And for starters, consider not using jQuery in AngularJS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The view is not updated when the model updates in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14374440/the-view-is-not-updated-when-the-model-updates-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery get callback method does not detect by angular because it outside of angular so need to inform angular of any update using `$scope.$apply()`

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
   jQuery.get( "/People/GetNumberOfUser", function( data )
   {
       $scope.testValue =data.message;
       $scope.$apply() ;
       alert(data.message);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
<p ng-controller="TestCtrl">
{{testValue}}
</p>
</div>
```

you can use angular $http instead of jquery then no need `$scope.$apply()`

```js
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope) 
{
    $http({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/People/GetNumberOfUser'
    }, function( data )
    {
       $scope.testValue =data.message;
       alert(data.message);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test">
<p ng-controller="TestCtrl">
{{testValue}}
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @31piy Thanks, i have update my coding using  `$http` service