# AngularJS and WebSockets: Callback function needs $scope.$apply() to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, websocket

I am using AngularJS and a phone web service to make calls through WebSockets.
The web service has several callbacks such as `Phone.onIncomingCall`

When I use this function to set a `$scope` variable the view is not updated automatically except if I use `$scope.$apply` right after.

```
Phone.onIncomingCall = function(){
  $scope.myVar = "newValue";
  $scope.$apply(); // only works if I call this line
};
```

**What is the reason for this behaviour (is it expected) and is there a way around using `$scope.apply()` in each function?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [The view is not updated in AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179488/the-view-is-not-updated-in-angularjs)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular is "unaware" of the update to the scope variable you've made, since you're updating it from outside of the Angular context. From the docs for [`$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply):

> $apply() is used to execute an expression in angular from outside of
>   the angular framework. (For example from browser DOM events,
>   setTimeout, XHR or third party libraries). Because we are calling into
>   the angular framework we need to perform proper scope life cycle of
>   exception handling, executing watches.

By running `$apply` on the scope, `$digest` is called from `$rootScope`, which will trigger any `$watch`ers registered on `$scope.myVar`. In this case, if you're using the variable in your view via interpolation, this is where the `$watch`er was registered from.

Answer (score 1):

It is the expected behavior, angular works like that internally.

I recommend the following:

```
Phone.onIncomingCall = function () {
    $scope.$apply(function () {
      $scope.myVar = 'newValue';
    });
}
```